# Why are escaped characters not allowed in SPARQL queries when using PREFIXes?

Tags: rdf, sparql, virtuoso

The following query throws `Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 0: Bad character '%' (0x25) in SPARQL expression at '%'`

```
PREFIX res: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX yago: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>
SELECT * WHERE {
  res:Reykjav%C3%ADk rdf:type yago:CapitalsInEurope ;
                     rdfs:label ?label ;
                     rdfs:comment ?abstract.
  FILTER (lang(?label) = "en" && lang(?abstract) = "en")
}
```

While this (forgive the pun) semantically identical query does not

```
PREFIX yago: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>
SELECT * WHERE {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Reykjav%C3%ADk> rdf:type yago:CapitalsInEurope ;
                     rdfs:label ?label ;
                     rdfs:comment ?abstract.
  FILTER (lang(?label) = "en" && lang(?abstract) = "en")
}
```

How come URL-escaped characters are not allowed in prefixed identifiers but are when giving the complete IRI?

Comment: They are in SPARQL 1.1.  Maybe the version you are using has not caught up yet - it was moderately done late in the spec cycle to align with Turtle in RDF 1.1.  http://www.sparql.org/query-validator.html

Comment: @AndyS I'm happily using SUM in some of my queries which, correct me if I'm wrong, was only implemented in SPARQL 1.1. Is there any way to find out the SPARQL version of an endpoint?

Comment: [SPARQL Service Description](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-service-description/) provides a means to describe the functionality of an endpoint including stating which SPARQL version it supports.  However just because an implementation claims it supports it doesn't necessarily mean it actually does, Virtuoso in particular is notorious for its poor compliance to the spec and love of non-standard extensions

Comment: @ThomasH Based on your queries, I wonder if you're running against the DBpedia endpoint?  It's based on Virtuoso which, besides a number of bugs and nonstandard behaviors, is somewhere in between SPARQL 1.1 and the original SPARQL.

Comment: @ThomasH, `res:Reykjavík` works.